# Create executable Tesseract installer for OSX?

Tags: python, tesseract

I am developing a Python program for which Tesseract is a core dependency.  I built it on PC with the understanding that Tesseract is OSX compatible (which it is).  What I did not know is that, unlike on Windows, it seems that you cannot simply execute a single installer file to easily have Tesseract running on OSX.  This will automatically alienate 99.9% of the users for my program.  The users of my program will not know what "the terminal" means, let-alone how to install brew, and definitely can't use it to install Tesseract.

Additionally, when I installed Tesseract via brew, it literally took more than an hour to complete, no idea why.  Admittedly I'm on a 2009 Mac running El Capitan but, anything longer than five minutes and a limited number of clicks on first install will be a no-go for my users.

So, what are my options?  Is it possible to somehow create an executable Tesseract installer for OSX?  Is it possible to automate the brew installation and subsequent Tesseract installation using a Python program executable?  Is my best bet to simply scrap the whole project given that 99% of my users will be on Mac?

I'm confused because I often use Tesseract functionality on Mac via Keybaord Maestro 9 and the installation for that takes about 10 seconds.  I'm a complete noob to programming so any help is greatly appreciated!  Thank you!

Comment: Did you check if any of [these](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/User-Projects-–-3rdParty) 3rd party apps install it for you? If so, could you require your users to install this as a requirement to use your product?

Comment: Another option would be to build yourself a script that would install both brew (if not installed) and tesseract. It would at most require the admin password... [this](http://macappstore.org/tesseract/) could give you a hint. I would recommend this last one as you would have more control over what you are asking your client to do, and would have no dependency on 3rd party sw.

Comment: I think the 3rd party sw idea is really promising.  PDF OCR X Community would be a good bet and might even be otherwise useful to users.  That said, legally it would probably be an issue for me to directly distribute it so I would need users to download and install it.  Also, now that I have tesseract and its dependencies installed, I can't confirm whether it will do the trick.  It should, right?  Hmm... testing required.

Comment: I thought of trying to script the installations via brew but, as I mentioned, the installation is incredibly long and cumbersome.  It could just be my ancient system but, who knows?  How long should it take to install Tesseract via brew?  It took my system almost an hour and a half and required three clicks on "Java required" warnings randomly during that time.  Users will never put up with that.  Thank you so much for the ideas!

Comment: I am on a MBP mid 2012  and did last installation on High Sierra, mine did not take so long. 

Do you actually need tesseract on their computers? Can you not process that on a server/cloud/platform...? Plus, whatever your application does, the execution of demanding stuff (such as OCR or text detection) would also be conditioned by their system... To much left to chance. Maybe you have to reconsider architecture.
About testing, you would have to uninstall and reinstall to test or get yourself a virtual machine, which is never as real, but...

Comment: Cloud-based OCR was, unfortunately, way too latent.  The code OCRs a new image every half-second.  If it fell behind by any more than two seconds it would become useless.  Given that the main applications my program is designed to enhance do not offer APIs to gather the data necessary, I'm relegated to OCR as the only option.  

I've tested it on many PCs successfully from old to new.  I've also used Keyboard Maestro's tesseract functionality to emulate it successfully on Macs but I need more features than KM offers and I can't ask users to pay $35 for it either.  I won't give up... yet.